# Conv Net upsampling to arbitrary size image

Tags: keras, conv-neural-network

I am experimenting with a conv–net structure (similar to u-net architecture, but without skip connections) that creates a mapping between images. Input image dimensions may (and will be) different from that of the output.

The model begins like this:

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=(x_w, x_h, 1), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Flatten())

        * * *

model.add(Conv2DTranspose(32, (3, 3), input_shape=(y_w, y_h, 1), activation='relu'))
```

What I can't understand is how to match dimensions in the * * * area to bring it to end up being y_w and y_h in the end. And if this is even possible.

I.e. given constraints of x_w, x_h and y_w, y_h, I need to dynamically build and architecture that would provide such a mapping.

Padding, cropping and pre/post-resizing is not an option.

Please help